# ggplot2 library installation in R Studio

Tags: r, rstudio

New to R Studio and wondering to install new package like ggplot2 (or any other additional packages/libraries), any convenient ways? Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work? Generally, `install.packages(c(vector_of_your_desired_packages))` is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka, I should ask if any user interface to manage/install package in R Studio like Eclipse/IDEA? Thanks.

Comment: I think the GUI of Rstudio allows for package-installation, but I always install packages using code... What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Heroka, I am just asking since we already use R Studio, if I could do package install by using any UI functions. :)

Comment: @Heroka, thanks and vote up. I think using command line is easier in my case and I am using command `install.packages("ggplot2")`, and wondering how to verify if package is installed correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Check if you can load the package (using `library(ggplot2)`)

Comment: @Heroka, thanks and vote up. Trying to use a wrong package name and there is error `> library(ggplot22)
Error in library(ggplot22) : there is no package called ‘ggplot22’`, and using right package name, there is no such errors, `> library(ggplot2)
> `. So, seems installation is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108974/discussion-between-heroka-and-lin-ma).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what Heroka said, which is the quickest way, except that you have to know the exact name of the package you want to install.

The other way is to go to the bottom right quadrant and select the "packages" tab and click on "install packages" above the list. This will open a new window where you will select what package you want to install, where on your system and from where. Also, there's auto-completion, so you just have to enter the first letters and select which package you want.

[image]

The advantage to doing things in script (`library(ggplot2)`) is that loading a package can be saved at the top of the script and easily run every time you run a script. Clicking cannot be saved, and must be done manually every time.

Comment: Thanks Amandine, vote up. I think using command line is easier in my case and I am using command `install.packages("ggplot2")`, and wondering how to verify if package is installed correctly? Thanks.

Comment: If the package isn't correctly installed, you'll have an error thrown. When you do the install, it tells you everything you need to know wether the installation was successful or not.

Comment: Thanks Amandine, and vote up. Trying to use a wrong package name and there is error `> library(ggplot22) Error in library(ggplot22) : there is no package called ‘ggplot22’`, and using right package name, there is no such errors, `> library(ggplot2) >` . So, seems installation is correct? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, Amandine. Mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `install.packages(ggplot2)` in the console of RStudio or another GUI and then load the package using `library(ggplot2)` afterwards. If you don't get any errors you're good to go